# Local names not resolved with static ip Rasbian stretch

Tags: dhcp, dns, raspbian-stretch

I've got a Nas doing DHCP and DNS ip adress = 192.168.0.1

local names are correctly resolved when raspberrypi-0-w ip is set to dynamic

```
pi@raspberrypi0-w2:~ $ ping munin
PING munin.cesan.lan (192.168.0.51) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.51 (192.168.0.51): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=5.07 ms
```

After setting static ip in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, adress is outside dhcp range

```
# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname
# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent
# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit
# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU. This is applied to DHCP routes.
option interface_mtu
# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier
# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private
# Static IP configuration:
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.0.53/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1
```

after reboot:

```
pi@raspberrypi0-w2:~ $ ping munin
ping: munin: Nom ou service inconnu
```

local host is unknown

If I ping with adress it's ok

```
pi@raspberrypi0-w2:~ $ ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.48 ms
```

if I ping outside LAN it seems to resolve the name but I don't get the ping

```
pi@raspberrypi0-w2:~ $ ping raspberrypi.stackexchange.com
PING raspberrypi.stackexchange.com (151.101.129.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

Is it a problem on Raspbian side or on the DNS side?

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: may i see your output of 'cat /etc/resolv.conf'

Comment: # Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 192.168.0.1

Comment: Do you have an entry in your /etc/hosts file such as : 192.168.0.1 munin

Comment: no, just standard hosts file

Comment: You should set `static domain_search=.local` to use non-fqdn based lookups, generally speaking this is specific to your router but `.local` is common (sometimes `.home` or something, it should be in router settings). You may also need to set `domain_name=.local` as well but search should be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

- Add the host IP to the local `hosts` file

**OR**

- Set the DNS Search domain in `dhcpcd.conf`

  `static domain_search=.local`

If you want the inverse of this (ping pi based on hostname only) You may also need to add

- `static domain_name=.local`  or `hostname_short`

---

DNS Lookups require a `Fully Qualified Domain Name (FQDN)`, e.g. `abc.com`

When you do a simple name lookup e.g. `ping abc`, unless the name is defined in the `hosts` file, it will not resolved. However, the setting `domain_search` ` adds one (or more) default domains to append to the dns lookup.

Your router will usually have a default domain, for example `.local`, but this may be different so look at the configurations

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything for me. I will stick to dhcp with some scripts on my NAS to make DHCP know to DNS which machine is connected.

Comment: I've been running a DNS server on my NAS for months and have very little in my hosts file, certainly not all the computers in my little corner of the internet. And I don't have any problem in lookups, even when I add a new computer.